# TP link router issue

Tags: router

I have a fairly new TP link router and I have to reset it (i.e. turn it off and on) everyday to work properly. Otherwise I get only half the internet speed if I don't reset it.

So I checked my firmware and it is one version old. So I download the new version from the Tplink site http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/?model=TL-WR340G&version=V4 here.

Its same as my router model. But the problem is when I open this file **tftpd32 it says "cannot initialize DHCP server insufficient privileges"**. Anyone knows why this error?

So any solutions apart from buying a new one.

Comment: Tell us more about your problem so we can help you diagnose it. What kind of Internet access do you have? How are you measuring your speed? What's the speed normally? What's the speed if you don't reset it? How long have you had this problem? Did this router ever work reliably with your Internet connection? Does it literally happen every day?

Comment: @David Schwartz -  I have a broadband of 2mb. I normally get upto "250kb/sec" when downloading anything from the internet. This is how I measure my speed. If I don't reset it speed goes down to 40 to 80kb/sec. I have had this problem for almost 1-2 months. Yes it worked fine before that. And yes it happens everytime I start my laptop after eight to nine hours of gap.

Comment: DSL? Cable? Satellite? Do you measure by downloading random things? Or do you test with something like speedtest.net?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you come to chat?
I measure with random things Yes. But it is ""apparent"" that I am losing speed. But after resetting it everything is fine.